# What is the correct property for flex-wrap in IE10?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, flexbox, internet-explorer-10

I am trying to use `flex-wrap`, but find it is not supported in IE10.

Is there any other flex property that could achieve the same result in IE10?

Comment: Just found out it -- `-ms-flex-wrap` is the replacement for flex-wrap.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All flex properties that work in IE10 can be found in Microsoft documentation:

- [**Flexible box ("Flexbox") layout in Internet Explorer 10**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh673531(v=vs.85).aspx)

For `flex-wrap` you would use `-ms-flex-wrap`.

Another option is to paste your code in the following tool, which automatically generates all the prefixes you need.

- [**Autoprefixer**](https://autoprefixer.github.io/)